# status bar overlapping my WebView screen, how to fix this?

Tags: flutter, webview, statusbar, overlap

I am building APK for my web app  but the upper part of the web app is overlapped by the status bar
I want to show the status bar but not overlap my Webview, Webview must use screen size except status bar

[check screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFe9K.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {

  runApp(const myapp());
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  const myapp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
  
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Sample App",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home:  const Scaffold(
            appBar: null  ,
          body: WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://primexop.com/motap/appw1/index.php?app_v=1.001010&ow_id=101',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `Scaffold` or `WebView` with a `SafeArea` widget?

Comment: thanks @PeterKoltai I got a solution how can I mention you in the answer?

Comment: no need, good to hear that you have your problem fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your Scaffold or WebView with SafeArea Widget

check the code below which fixes this issue

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const myapp());
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class myapp extends StatelessWidget {
  const myapp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Sample App",
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const  SafeArea(
child:  Scaffold(
          appBar: null,
          
          body: WebView(
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            initialUrl: "https://primexop.com/motap/appw1/index.php?app_v=1.001010&ow_id=101",
            
          )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used SafeArea to wrap the Scaffold

[Result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QehOX.jpg)